# Advance a list [1,2,3] to [3,1,2] in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to write a simple OCaml program to advance a vector, that is [1,2,3] goes to [3,1,2] and so on:

```
open Printf

let advance_list list =
    match list with 
    |[]   -> []
    |h::t -> t::h

let () = List.iter (printf "%d ") (advance_list [1;2;3])
```

but I get

```
File "rotate_vector.ml", line 13, characters 16-17:
13 |     |h::t -> t::h
                     ^
Error: This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type
         'a list list
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list list
```

I don't undrstand the error. For me I'm returning the first element appended to the start of `h` which is the list without the first element which is `t`

Comment: You have to use the list concatenation operator.

Comment: @G4143 `h @ [t]` rigth? I just noticed that I'm not doing what the exercise does. Do you know how to match instead of `first:rest`, do `rest:last`? I need to pick the last element and put into the front

Comment: Try to break the problem into smaller pieces. First write a function to get the last element, then extend that to return the last element and the rest of the list without the last element, then write a function using that to put the last element first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The head and tail of a list are not the same type. For a list of type `t list`, the head of the list is of type `t`, but the tail of the list is of type `t list`. In other words, the tail of a list is also a list.

So, you can't use the `::` operator to switch them around. You need something of type `t` at the left and something of type `t list` at the right.

At any rate, you need to split the list at the end rather than the beginning. For that you'll need something a little more complicated. I could imagine a function that traverses the list, keeping track of what it's seen so far (the beginning of the list) and then putting together the result when it gets to the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
let get_last_elt l = 
 let list_rev = List.rev l in
  match list_rev with 
  [] -> failwith "The list is empty"
  |h::t -> let end_of_list = h in end_of_list

let delete_last_elt l = 
 let list_rev = List.rev l in
  match list_rev with 
  [] -> failwith "The list is empty"
  |h::t -> List.rev t

let advance_list l = 
 let end_of_list = get_last_elt l in
  match l with
  [] -> failwith "The list is empty"
  |h::t -> [end_of_list]@(delete_last_elt l)
```

I hope this helps !